# Unable to use jquery in nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am newbie to Javascript/jquery. I am writing a simple js file that parses a csv file.

```
var jquery = require('jquery');

jquery.get('file.csv', function(data) {
   alert(data); // this is a line
   var tempArray = data.split(','); // array of data
   for(var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++)
   {
       console.log(tempArray[i]); // probably index 1 is your IPv6 address.
   }
});
```

When I run the code above, I get the following error:

```
jquery.get('file.csv', function(data) {
       ^

TypeError: jquery.get is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ishabir1/Desktop/transloc/parser.js:3:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Can someone please advise? Thanks!

Comment: Dude, try not to use client side libraries on server-side. They will mess things up. Node has various modules to play with file system and parsing data, where `fs` in a core module.

Comment: @Nivesh you're right. I was confusing the client vs server side frameworks. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use jQuery like that in the Node.js realm.

You need to rely on the [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module for reading files, and on a [csv library](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv-parse) for actually parsing your data, [see example](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv-parse/blob/master/samples/fs_read.js):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var parse = require('csv').parse;

var parser = parse(function(err, data){
  console.log(data);
});

fs.createReadStream('file.csv').pipe(parser);
```

Don't forget to run `npm install csv` before requiring it!

Comment: what does this line do: var parse = require('..');

Comment: I npm installed csv, and now I get the error that parse is not a function.

Comment: See edit again, I took the example from the `csv-parse`submodule.

Comment: Thank you, it does work now! Is this the best way to parse a csv file in a nodejs application?

Comment: If you want to be a **Jedi** in `csv` parsing kindly refer to [node-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv) and there [Github repo](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv)